# Writing many values received in real time to database on iPhone with SQLite3

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I'm currently writing an iOS app and I have many records that I'm writing to a database.
Even though with the iPhone you are writing to flash memory, the ram still has a faster access time.
To improve performance I am writing to a temporary cache in ram and then at one point I append that cache to the database.

What is a standard practice / technique with knowing how often to write the cache to the database?
How can I fine tune this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with a cache that needed to be flushed to a server instead of a local DB.  I used instruments to find the "typical" size of one of the cached objects (mine were fairly uniformed) and I just maintain a count of how many are in the cache and when I cross the threshold I empty my cache to the server.  I then learned about NSCache that has much of this same behavior.  I investigated ways to dynamically determine the size of each object in the cache, but found it tedious and brittle.
Basically, I think you need to decide what makes sense from your app based on the usage characteristics gathered with instruments.  I found the video from the 2011 WWDC conference "Section 318 - iOS Performance in Depth" to be very helpful for similar situations.  You can find it on itunes U.